# UPDATE multiple fields under same condition (IF or CASE)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update, case

Need some help. There are some questions and answers here about this topic but didn't found one that fits my need.

I have these two queries:

```
UPDATE leilaov
   SET seconds = CASE
      WHEN (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
        OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
        OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
        OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())) THEN seconds-1
   END
WHERE numero12345 = 1


UPDATE leilaov
   SET seconds = IF((mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
                OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
                OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
                OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())), seconds-1, seconds)
WHERE numero12345 = 1
```

Both work fine and there are no significant differences in execution time.
The problem is that I need to update several fields and not just only one.

Whats the syntax to update several fields? Do I have to repeat the condition to each field?

Should I use CASE or IF? Or is there another better option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need to repeat your case for every field you're trying to set. So you'd do this:

```
UPDATE leilaov
   SET seconds = CASE
      WHEN (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
        OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
        OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
        OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())) THEN seconds-1
   END,
, second_field = CASE
          WHEN (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
            OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
            OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
            OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())) THEN seconds-1
       END

WHERE numero12345 = 1
```

It looks to me that there's either something wrong with your table structure or you should consider using multiple queries to solve your issue instead.

EDIT: Since I'm a big fan of code readability, **if performance is not an issue and never will be**, I'd do it in two steps:

1. Loop through all eligible records (In MySQL or your back-end language of choice)
2. Edit the record inside the loop before updating it, you won't need to repeat your condition twice if you do this right.

Over-optimization is bad, in most cases, code readability is more important.

Comment: Thanks @Dany Caissy. Regarding your comment about table structure, unfortunatly was inherited.

Comment: Thanks again @Dany Caissy. Your comment about table structure made me think why was I taking for granted what I had inherited and, guess what? I rebuild that structure and coding is now shorter, easier, much more readable and, as a bonus, performance is better too. ;)

Comment: Cool, don't forget to upvote or accept answers you appreciate.

Comment: Hi again @Dany Caissy! Jesus!!! I'm really a newbie at this. Where or how do I upvote your answer???

Comment: Top left of my answer there's an "up" and a "down" arrow, around the "0". You should also have an option to accept an answer near there.